# how to return undefined if there is no property at the given key?

Tags: javascript

I am doing javascript problems, and here is a problem that I got 1/2 answer right. I don't know how to return undefined if there is no property at the given key. Here is the problem and my code for the problem.

"Given an object and a key, "getProperty" returns the value of the property at the given key.

Notes:
* If there is no property at the given key, it should return undefined."

```
function getProperty(obj, key) {
  for (var x in obj) {
    return obj[x];
  }
}
```

Comment: The loop is useless giving that you return from the very first iteration.

Comment: `function getProperty(obj, key) { return obj[key]; }` will return either the value or `undefined`.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `hasOwnProperty` function, Example:

```js
function getProperty(obj, key){
  return obj.hasOwnProperty(key) ?obj[key] : undefined; 
}

// Examples
console.log(getProperty({a: 1, b: 2}, "a"));
console.log(getProperty({a: 1, b: 2}, "c"));
```

**Update** You can do it in simpler way

```js
function getProperty(obj, key){
      return obj[key]; 
}

// Examples
console.log(getProperty({a: 1, b: 2}, "a"));
console.log(getProperty({a: 1, b: 2}, "c"));
```

Comment: Both are ok. Although I prefer the first as it won't look in the prototype chain.

Comment: I think only the second is valid. It doesn't say only return own properties, it says property.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a function for that. Just call it directly:

```
obj[key]; // Return value or 'undefined' if not found.
```

Also, your function is useless. It only returns the first value found in obj

If you really want a function, just this will do

```
function getProperty(obj, key) {
    return obj[key];
}
```